# SqlDataReader in xDocument (in C#)

Tags: c#, sql

My program loads data from the database and builds an html file from strings. I use xDocument for this (using System.Xml; using System.Xml.Linq).

Please look at my code. In place '1234' in `string code` I need a `reader["SQL_Code"]` because I would like to display this data from the database.
I don't know how I can solve this problem?

```
var table_dynamic10 = new XElement("tr");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                string query = string.Format("{0}{1}'", "SELECT [SQL_Code] ...");
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        string code = "JsBarcode(\"#code128\", \"1234\", {width: 1, height: 30, displayValue: true});";
                        // https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            table_dynamic10.Add(
                            new XElement("tr",
                            new XElement("td", new XElement("svg", new XAttribute("id", "code128")), new XElement("script", code)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

UPDATE: Okay, I know how to solve this problem. I make a new object, but I dont know, why this no compile, because: `System.FormatException: 'Invalid input string format.'`

```
                    string test;
                    int index = 1;
                    object r = reader["SQL_Code"];
                    test = Convert.ToString(r);
                    var code = string.Format("<script>JsBarcode(\"#code128\", \"{0}\", {width: 1, height: 30, displayValue: true});</script>", test);
```

Comment: You can't reference the reader until you start to "read", so you you would put `string code = reader["SQL_Code"]` wihin the `while` loop..

Comment: @stuartd I've already done it, but a new problem arose.

Comment: @Igor: `System.FormatException: 'Invalid input string format.'`

Comment: See the marked duplicate, the answer in the duplicate question will explain why you are getting that exception on `string.Format`

Comment: Suggest you use the `GetString` method of the reader - `var code = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("SQL_Code"));`